# What tool should I use to harvest cocoa beans?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing Minecraft survival mode and I found some cocoa beans. I traveled a far distance to find jungle log and then return to my sanctuary, plant beans on jungle logs.

When they grew, I used my hand to pick them up but they were destroyed and I got no beans. I also used shovel but no more results: I lost my beans, unfortunately.

So in a creative world I use to test things, I grew some beans.

**How am I suppose to pick them up without destroying them?**
I searched a bit but no one mentioned that!

[image]

As you can see, beans are in 3 stages of growth. The big brown is the right time to harvest, isn't it?

Comment: This sounds like server lag or the gamerule "doTileDrops" being off. Have you tried it in a freshly created Singleplayer world?

Comment: @FabianRöling i tried. no difference

Comment: Make sure you're in survival mode while harvesting the beans. If you break them in creative mode, no items will drop

Comment: Would be helpful is you specified version of the game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always used the hand for cocoa beans, and I never had any problem. It may be a problem of lag, or the versión you are using, I would recommend you to use the latest version available. For example: if you are using 1.12.1 switch to 1.12.2, or if you are using 1.14 switch to 1.14.4. If you are already using the latest version, try deleting the version from the “versions” folder on %appdata%.minecraft and running the game on that version again.

Answer (score 0):

Use an axe. Iron is fine, but diamond is faster. You may have a problem with gamemodes, however.

Comment: No, that is not true. Axes make it faster, but they are definitely not required.